# C# get parameter from url after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, linkedin-api

I have a redirect:

```
  string linkedInLogin = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=ID&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=ZEKNI&scope=r_basicprofile";
  Response.Redirect(linkedInLogin);
```

This results in a redirect in my browser to

> https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin?code=CODE_I_NEED&state=STATE

How do I retrieve the value of the code paramater?

`Request.Querystring["code"]` gives me a `null` value. The problem is that the browser "thinks" the current URL was `/home/MyController`.

Comment: Does `Request["state"]` work?

Comment: No the problem is that the browser "thinks" the current URL /home/MyController

Comment: Why is that a problem? What did you expect then?

Comment: https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin?code=CODE_I_NEED&state=STATE

Comment: because I get that URL in my browser

Comment: you get that because that is what you are passing in the redirect_uri parameter on the original request. Change that parameter's value to point to your action's url.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["code"]
```

this way you can get a combined collection of `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookies`, and `ServerVariables` items.

here you can read more: [HttpRequest.Params Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: the problem is that the browser "thinks" the current URL /home/MyController

Comment: i don't get it. but if you want continue the request after redirect try  this:  Response.Redirect(linkedInLogin,false)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have that link stored somewhere or are you asking for how to retrieve it as well?

Assuming you already have it:

```
var s = "https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin?
code=CODE_I_NEED&state=ROB962242SMUT"
```

You can either do:

```
string s = "https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin?code=CODE_I_NEED&state=ROB962242SMUT";
var code = s.Substring((s.IndexOf("code=") + 5), (s.IndexOf('&') - (s.IndexOf("code=") + 5)));

//CODE_I_NEED
```

Or

```
String sourcestring = "https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin?
code=CODE_I_NEED&state=ROB962242SMUT";
Regex re = new Regex(@"code=(.*)&");
var result =Match m = re.Match(sourcestring).Value;

//CODE_I_NEED
```

edit: based on the other two answers i may not have understood your question properly xd

Comment: No I don't have the response URI on advance. The CODE_I_NEED will be different for everyone.

Comment: But that piece code utilises string manipulation to retrieve whatever is in that parameter?